# YouTube API: 'Official' Tag

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

When you search for a music video on YouTube, there often appears a video tagged 'Official' in the results. Example:

[image: Example]

Is there a way to retrieve this flag by an API call?

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEOID?v=2 does not have any field that might indicated such a tag.

Comment: This is such a new feature on Youtube, thats why they didn't update their API yet. Take a look here: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html , this is the list of all youtube API features. It may help.

Comment: @Raj , Replace the `VIDEOID` with the video code from the URL I guess.

Answer (score 4):

IMO, official is not per song, but per channel. In acdcVEVO's [user profile](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/acdcvevo), you can see its channel type set to "Musician". Most users are "Standard".

Comment: I don't think that’s quite right; on our videos (GTDReviews) the official tag only shows up on one of them, as far as I can see.